# graphql: Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `graphql`

Tags: relayjs

Trying to use Relay Modern in my app and constantly getting

```
Uncaught Error: graphql: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the 
Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call 
site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `graphql`.
at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at graphql (RelayModernGraphQLTag.js:24)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (Task.js:10)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (Task.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:657)
    at fn (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (TaskList.js:4)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (TaskList.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:657)
    at fn (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (TasksScreen.js:9)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (TasksScreen.js:48)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:657)
    at fn (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:85)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e8e4676bb8dac281d3e7:657)
```

Although babel-plugin-relay configured and used the code does not gets transpiled. TasksScreenAllTasksQuery.graphql.js file generated and on proper place.

Babel seems to be setup correctly since the plugin gets called.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "relay",
      {
        "schema": "./dist/schema.graphql"
      }
    ],
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "rewire"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

TasksScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { graphql, QueryRenderer } from 'react-relay';
import Spinning from 'grommet/components/icons/Spinning';

import { environment } from '../../../relay';

const TasksScreenAllTasksQuery = graphql`
  query TasksScreenAllTasksQuery {
    viewer {
      task(id: "VGFzazpmY2QwNTBlMi01Zjk0LTRmMjktOWVlMC1lMGMwMmQzMTE5YzQ=") {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default class TasksScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={TasksScreenAllTasksQuery}
        render={({ error, props }) => {
          if (error) {
            return <div>{error.message}</div>;
          } else if (props) {
            return <div>{props.viewer.task.id}</div>;
          }
          return <Spinning />;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Debugging babel-plugin-relay I observed that [getValidGraphQLTag](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/v1.2.0-rc.1/packages/babel-plugin-relay/getValidGraphQLTag.js#L28) checks node for Identifier type but the checked node is of type CallExpression. Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

babel-plugin-rewire caused the problem. Removing rewire from .babelrc does the job.